# Where can I find python.exe file in Anaconda?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using jupyter notebook (in Anaconda) to code in python language. I know in Anaconda, we do not need to install the python.exe file because that is in Anaconda. I want to find the python.exe file in the place that Anaconda is installed but I cannot find it. Could you please let me know where I can find it?

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.executable)` would probably tell you i guess

Answer (score 1):

If you are a windows user & installed anaconda in default path then go to c drive -> open User folder then look for username you installed under that user inside that folder there will be folder name as anaconda3 & open the folder, you will see python.exe file.

Example path: C:\Users{your user name here}\anaconda3  -> It will be available in the main folder itself

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed it in D drive but according to your guidance, I could find it. Thank you again.